# Check if QVariant is convertible to other QVariant type

Tags: qt

I receive data in JSON using a `QJsonObject`. I also have a `QObject`-based object holding properties, using `Q_PROPERTY(...)`, for the keys in the JSON. Since Qt now has some more datatypes than JSON how can one check if they are convertible.

The datatypes used in the object typically are one of the following but not limited to

```
uint
double
QString
QDateTime
bool
```

The idea is to automatically call `setProperty(...)` on the QOject derived object for every key/value in the `QJsonObject`. Since this could fail due to malformed input in the JSON I have to check validity based on the `QMetaProperty` and `QJsonObject/QVariantMap` data.

Since this should run generic as a base class implementing manual checks for every datatype fails. I know there is `QVariant::isConvertible<T>()`.

```
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaProperty>
class Test {
  Q_GADGET
  Q_PROPERTY(QString test)

  QString m_test;
  QJsonObject jo;

  void call();
}

void Test::call()
{
    jo.insert("test",QJsonValue(5));

    // This will fail, since int is not convertible to QString implicitly
    staticMetaObject->property(staticMetaObject->propertyOffset()).writeOnGadget(this,jo["test"].toVariant());
}
```

Since I am parsing the JSON before to check if every property would have a corresponding key in the JSON-Object I really like to catch these there already without changing my original object. Something like:

```
jo["test"].toVariant().canConvert<staticMetaObject->property(staticMetaObject->propertyOffset()).type()>()
```

Comment: Actually I found the solution on the last line... There is `bool QVariant::canConvert(int targetTypeId)` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using templated `bool QVariant::canConvert<T>()` one can use `bool QVariant::canConvert(int targetTypeId)`.

```
QMetaProperty po = staticMetaObject->property(staticMetaObject->propertyOffset());
jo["test"].toVariant().canConvert(po.type());
```